# XML Comments -- How do you comment explicitly implemented interfaces properly?

Tags: c#, xml-comments, explicit-interface, explicit-implementation

**Code:**

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

public class FooClass : IFoo
{
    /// <summary> ... </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="?"/> //How do you reference the IFoo.Bar() method
    public void Bar() { }

    /// <summary> ... </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="?"/> //How do you reference the standard Bar() method
    void IFoo.Bar() { }
}
```

My guess is:

```
<seealso cref="IFoo.Bar()"/> //Explicitly implemented interface method
<seealso cref="Bar()"/>      //Standard method
```

but, I'm not sure. The ECMA guide didn't help distinguish, so I guess I'm looking for assurance that my guess is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test with Sandcastle Help File Builder revealed that in the created documentation the link `<seealso cref="IFoo.Bar()"/>` points to the method in the interface and `<seealso cref="Bar()"/>` points to the method in the class. The documentation for the explicitly implemented method is inherited from the interface so you should actually point to the interface method anyway.

Edit: ReSharper also complains with `<seealso cref="FooClass.IFoo.Bar()"/>` and corrects it to be `<seealso cref="IFoo.Bar()"/>` which then points to the interface method, not the explicitly implemented one.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wasn't 100% sure. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: So is there no way to reference the explicitly defined interface method through xml comments?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<seealso cref="M:FooClass.IFoo#Bar"/>`. This is the syntax used in the XML document comments file.

And don't forget to prefix the namespace for both the class and the interface. If `FooClass` and `IFoo` resided in `FooNamespace`, you'd have to write `<seealso cref="M:FooNamespace.FooClass.FooNamespace#IFoo#Bar"/>`. Methods with arguments need a fully qualified parameter list.

You won't get Intellisense for this. And the compiler won't complain if you got the syntax wrong. You'll need to test this with your document generator.

I tested this with sandcastle and it works, but it's too brittle to seriously use it.